# Javascript Load Font from another site

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, code-snippets

So I code purely for fun and have bookmark folders full of snippets I can run on random webpages and force the website to obey my command. So I decided to challenge myself: Make a snippet that changes all the font on a webpage to a different font. My font of choice? A Breath of the Wild-style font. The problem is: I cannot load the font on any page except the one I have imported it to (a repl.it subdomain). Please help if this is even possible, or if I am just being dumb.

The URL that should work is: `https://dumpingbox.konstrictor.repl.co/files/HyliaSerifBeta-Regular.woff`
It works on the original page without the first part of the URL (starting with `/files/`)

Comment: You may have some CORS issues. do you see any errors in the console log?

Comment: not sure what you mean... also the computer I use doesn't allow developer tools :(

Comment: which browser are using? most browsers if you hit F12 it opens the developer tools.there is usually a "Console" tab there that will display error messages when you load a page.

Comment: It is a school/work computer, and certain features are disabled, so I cannot test that. Thank you, though

Comment: what browser is it? and which OS are you using?

Comment: Chrome/ChromeOS on a dell chromebook

Comment: So what happens when you hit the F12 button while in Chrome?

Comment: Actually, a chromebook doesn't have F12, but when you hit the usual shortcut, nothing happens. The owner of the computer disabled it.

Comment: try rightclick->inspect or ctrl-shift-i

Comment: I told you, that doesn't work. It is disabled. Can you help me answer my question please?

Comment: look you didn't provide any code to go off of. I am only trying to help you. Try another computer if its disabled on that one, paste some code here so we can give somewhere to start. have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Ok sorry I was mean. Thanks for your advice